# 2009 Volvo S40 sudden thump

Tags: fuel-system, transmission, volvo, vibration, s40

When at constant speed I notice a slight thump. Almost as if for a split second the car lost fuel to the engine then kicks back in. It does not register on the instruments. Also at lower speeds it can get shaky especially when decelerating. Taking it to the dealer Monday. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a constant or intermittent "thump"? What speed does it register? Have you had any work done to your car lately? Has it just come about (as in all of a sudden), or has it gotten worse over time?

Comment: Could it be something not engine run related? I'm thinking engine or transmission mounts. They tend to thump when the rubber rots out.

Comment: OP never responded to initial questions.  I'm voting to close this as a result.   Too broad.